# How to Know the printer name (Not default printer name) using java?

Tags: java

I have added two printers (using Ricoh universal printer Driver) on same port number,it is working fine.I have written a java program to read the stream from the socket and write into postscript file .As I am running two printers on same port I am able to print the file through both the printers .But my question is, **How can I know that from which printer the print/Stream is coming?**

I know that we can get the default printer name as below 
PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService().

Answer (score 0):

```
import javax.print.*;

class Test {

public static void main (String [] args)
{
    PrintService[] printServices = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null);
    System.out.println("Number of print services: " + printServices.length);

    for (PrintService printer : printServices)
        System.out.println("Printer: " + printer.getName()); 
}
```

}
Use above code to get list of printers then check for state of every printer, if it is busy in job then your stream is coming from that printer

```
PrintService printService = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
AttributeSet attributes = printService.getAttributes();
String printerState = attributes.get(PrinterState.class).toString();
String printerStateReason = attributes.get(PrinterStateReason.class).toString();

System.out.println("printerState = " + printerState);
if(printerState.equals(javax.print.attribute.standard.PrinterState.PROCESSING)){
//this is printer from where stream is coming 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. If we have queue of prints waiting  in one printer and  another printer is printing the present file ,in that case how can we know ?

Comment: Thats the key, your printer state will be marked as "busy" not "waiting"